# How to add Label/text in Bokeh that can be auto rescaled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I learnt how to add text by using `Label` in `Bokeh` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696486/how-can-i-add-text-annotation-in-bokeh).

 However, I found that the text doesn't rescale as I zoom in and out.

 The ideal behavior is something like `Patches`, which becomes larger as you zoom in.

 How can I configure for this feature?

 **Related Questions**

- [Selectively show text in Bokeh plot based on zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164874/selectively-show-text-in-bokeh-plot-based-on-zoom-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 2.3 scalable text is still an open issue:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9407

There are some potential partial workarounds discussed there, but nothing that concretely works all the time. Depending on your use case, you could potentially use [`CustomJS` callback on the plot ranges](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-ranges) to update the text size that you care about in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround (using CustomJS, as suggested in a previous answer as well). This solution dynamically finds the current zoom level using the current start and end values of the x axis, and modifies the font size accordingly. I tested this on Bokeh 3.1.1.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import Label, DataRange1d, CustomJS

PLOT_INIT_X_MAX = 10

# set output to HTML file
output_file(filename="text_scale.html")

# create a new plot with specific size and tools
p = figure(width=500, height=300, tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset", active_scroll ="wheel_zoom")

# set the initial x range
p.x_range = DataRange1d(start=0, end=PLOT_INIT_X_MAX)

# add sample circle plot
p.circle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], size=5)

# add sample text
sample_text = Label(x=5, y=5, text='sample text')
p.add_layout(sample_text)

# handle dynamic text rescaling with CustomJS
# cb_obj.start and cb_obj.end are the start and end values of x axis
x_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(sample_text=sample_text, init_font_size=sample_text.text_font_size[:-2], init_xrange=PLOT_INIT_X_MAX), code="""
let xzoom = (init_font_size * init_xrange) / (cb_obj.end - cb_obj.start);
sample_text['text_font_size'] = String(xzoom) + 'pt';
""")
p.x_range.js_on_change('start', x_callback)

# save the results to HTML file
save(p)
```